# Spring boot - Setting configration property thru program arguments

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and the setting file with the below annotation.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("test.prop")
public class TestPropSettings {
  private String name;
}
```

The following property in the application.properties set this value.

```
test.prop.name=XYZ
```

But, I would like to pass thru program arguments without having the property file.

Tried with,

`-Dtest.prop.name=XYZ` in eclipse program arguments. But, it does not work. Is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a **program argument** not a system property! You have conflated the two `-Dxxx=yyy` as a program argument is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start your jar directly, you can override the property like this:

```
java -jar your-app.jar --test.prop.name=XYZ
```

In Eclipse you also need to pass `--test.prop.name=XYZ` in you program arguments.

Comment: Might be worth outlining the difference between arguments to the `java` executable, including system properties, and arguments to the application that Java runs.